# metaio obj files can't read jpeg files

Tags: android, png, jpeg

I've been using the metaio sdk for Android for quite some time and i wanted to change my textures from .PNG to JPEG. But it doesn't work, does Metaio allow only .PNG file to be read with Obj file ?

Comment: Are you able to open the new obj file in an editor or obj viewer? Might be pointless but it eliminates any issues which are not directly caused by the engine-jpg use.

Answer (score 0):

no it doesn't.  checkout this [tutorial](http://docs.metaio.com/bin/view/Main/HelloAugmentedWorldExample) which uses a .jpg file.